# How to Enable Floating point Numbers After Applying Pattern with DecimalFormat

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing a Convertor Application and I want a thousand separator automatically added to the digits in realtime, so after I implemented this applypattern code on the TextWatcher, now I can not make floationg point inputs.....here is my code for the Editext

```
am2 = new TextWatcher()
{
  boolean isEdiging;
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if (s.toString().equals("")) {
    amount.setText("");
    value = 0;
 }else{
 if(isEdiging) return;
 isEdiging = true;
 StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
 char c;
 for (int i = 0; i < amount2.getText().toString().length() ; i++) {
     c = amount2.getText().toString().charAt(i);
     if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    strBuff.append(c);
     }
 }
value = Double.parseDouble(strBuff.toString());
reverse();
NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("###,###.#######");
s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(value));
isEdiging = false;
}
}
};
```

So is there any way of inputting floating point within the EditText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class solves the problem

```
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
private DecimalFormat df;
private DecimalFormat dfnd;
private boolean hasFractionalPart;

private EditText et;

public NumberTextWatcher(EditText et)
{
    df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
    df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    this.et = et;
    hasFractionalPart = false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    try {
        int inilen, endlen;
        inilen = et.getText().length();

        String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
        Number n = df.parse(v);
        int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
        if (hasFractionalPart) {
            et.setText(df.format(n));
        } else {
            et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
        }
        endlen = et.getText().length();
        int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
        if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
            et.setSelection(sel);
        } else {
            // place cursor at the end?
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // do nothing?
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // do nothing?
    }

    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
    {
        hasFractionalPart = true;
    } else {
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }
}
```

}